# Open a text file in new tab

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, file, webforms

I have a `text` file in my local drive. I want to show the content of it in a new tab.

I have tried the following

**1st Try**

```
   string fileName = @"C:\MyFile.log";
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "windowKey", "window.open('" + fileName + "');", true);
```

**2nd Try**

```
    Response.Write("<script>");
    Response.Write("window.open('C:\\MyFile.log', '_newtab');");
    Response.Write("</script>");
```

*Both of these open in new tab but the data inside the file is not displaying*

After some search, I found this

```
    FileStream MyFileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\MyFile.log", FileMode.Open);
    long FileSize;
    FileSize = MyFileStream.Length;
    byte[] Buffer = new byte[(int)FileSize];
    MyFileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, (int)MyFileStream.Length);
    MyFileStream.Close();
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=sample.txt");
    Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);
```

*This is displaying the content in my file but along with that it is also displaying my `aspx` page*

**So my question is how to show a text file in a new tab**

Comment: @madalinivascu okay, Can you tell me how would I specify my path

Comment: you use a link with a href like you link a page to another lol

Comment: @madalinivascu I have tried this `<a href="C:/MyFile.log" id="hplTest" runat="server">link</a>` and got the error in the `console` as **Not allowed to load local resource**

Comment: @madalinivascu How can you specify the above path relatively? Help me, I have no clue about this

Comment: first copy the file in folder where you have the asp page with your link in it, then at the href you just put the name of the file

Comment: @madalinivascu I cannot do that, because it gets updated whenever my code runs and I have to be upto date. This copying doesn't allow me to do that

Comment: alter the code that generates the file to put the file in the that folder

Answer (score 0):

try those steps

- create a log.aspx and put the code from the third snippet to it.
- use 1st or 2nd snippet to open log.aspx in the new window (tab)

that way it should work.

Comment: I don't want to create another `aspx` for that

Answer (score 0):

I have tried like this:

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Button id="btnShowContent" Text="Show me the text" runat="server" OnClick="btnShowContent_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
protected void btnShowContent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OpenTextFile", "Javascript:window.open('Resources/test.txt');", true);
}
```

You just need to update your file path.
Hope this is what you want.